# Have SSD with Windows 7, ubuntu 13.04 installed but GRUB does not work

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu several times and GRUB does not work.  I tried using the boot repair tool and this always gives an error that is not informative.  I saw when creating the drive that there was a Windows Loader partition and Ubuntu proposed sda upon which also had the loader partion.  What can I do to get this to work?  Anyone have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

My "work" laptop ... Lenovo w530 came with Windows 7 Enterprise
and two partitions: 
500MB boot partition 
179GB rest of disk partition

I used clonezilla to copy that entire disk to a larger 320GB drive then resized the Windows partition back to just the 180GB size so I could install ubuntu 13.04

Installed Ubuntu as normal and it installed Grub but on reboot the machine boots directly into windows and not to the GRUB menu screen?

I've reinstalled Grub twice now and the same thing.  So I'll have to look back at this 2 partition scheme Lenovo preinstalled and see whats different about it.